# Why my R function is showing me Length class mode instead of frequencies?

Tags: r

I am currently taking a course in statistics, and they asked us to install R and R environment to use during the course. This my first time using R.
Our first task is to test some csv files
using these commands:

```
ex.1 <- read.csv('ex1.csv')
summary(ex.1)
colnames(ex.1)
```

The results should look like this:

```
       id                          sex                      height     
Min.   :1538611                 FEMALE:54               Min.   :117.0  
1st Qu.:3339583                 MALE  :46               1st Qu.:158.0  
Median :5105620                                         Median :171.0  
Mean   :5412367                                         Mean   :170.1  
3rd Qu.:7622236                                         3rd Qu.:180.2  
Max.   :9878130                                         Max.   :208.0
```

However, I am getting this (I included my entire code):

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/hp/Documents"
> setwd("C:/Users/hp/Documents/R")
> dir()
[1] "ex1.csv"     "ex2.csv"     "flowers.csv" "pop1.csv"    "pop2.csv"   
[6] "pop3.csv"    "win-library"
> ex.1 <- read.csv('ex1.csv')
> summary(ex.1)
       id              sex                height     
 Min.   :1538611   Length:100         Min.   :117.0  
 1st Qu.:3339583   Class :character   1st Qu.:158.0  
 Median :5105620   Mode  :character   Median :171.0  
 Mean   :5412367                      Mean   :170.1  
 3rd Qu.:7622236                      3rd Qu.:180.2  
 Max.   :9878130                      Max.   :208.0  
> colnames(ex.1)
[1] "id"     "sex"    "height"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. @Damandeep
It worked. Can you explain what is happening? I'd like to know.
Also, how would I make it happen permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this `ex.1$sex<- as.factor(ex.1$sex)` . Then try summary command

The thing is when you are reading it as csv it reads sex column as characters. You have to make it as factor.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that R is reading the sex column as a string of text and not acknowledging that all cells with "MALE" in them should be grouped as should all "FEMALE" cells. So it reports that the cells have text in them where as you want a special form of text which is a factor. as.factor() forces R to recognise the same text string as from a particular group.

How to stop it from doing it next time. One way is to add the argument ' stringsAsFactors = T ' to your "read.csv" command. e.g.

```
read.csv('ex1.csv', stringAsFactors = T)
```

This coerces the strings which are read by R to become factors.